# Index out of range in mysql using java.....!

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans, character-encoding

Below is my code and i am getting an exception index out of range and i am not able to figure out why .I am using netbeans IDE. Is it because of that '#' character and  i did't find any trouble creating a table with name 'A #' or 'B'.

```
class DBS{
public boolean insertAt(String tableName){
    String query ;
    String insertAt;
    java.sql.TimeStamp sysTime;
    boolean result
    Switch(tableName){
        case "A":
            sysTime = 
            insertAt = "A";
            String query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO "+ insertAt +"(Name,Location,Time) VALUES(?,?,?)";
            preparedStmt.setString(1,"xName");
            preparedStmt.setString(2,"xLocation");
            preparedStmt.setTimeStamp(3,)
            preparedStmt = conn.execute(query);
            result = true;
            preparedStmt = null;
            break;
        case "B":
            insertAt = "B #";
            String query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO "+ insertAt +"(Name,Location,Time,Address) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
            preparedStmt.setString(1,"yName");
            preparedStmt.setString(2,"yLocation");
            preparedStmt.setTimeStamp(3,sysTime);
            preparedStmt.setString(4,"yAddress")
            preparedStmt = conn.execute(query);
            preparedStmt = null;
            result = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
public static void main(String[] args){

    String[] tableNames = {"A #"," b"};
    if(new  DBS().insertAt(tableNames[1]) && new DBS().insertAt(tableNames[0])){
        System.out.println("insertion success");    
    }else{
        System.out.println("insertion failed");
}
}
}
```

Comment: is that possible preparedStmt.setTimeStamp(3,) ?

Comment: Also it´s a bit confusing that you are using the `PreparedStatement` correct and incorrect at the same. You are using the `?` for the values of the columns, while you are just concatinating the table name into the statement.

Comment: furthermore you forgott the ; here "boolean result"

Comment: There are multiple syntax errors in the code  above. It's not giving you an NPE or any other exception; it's not getting that far.

Comment: @KevinEsche oh  i am sorry it was preparedStatement.setTimeStamp(3,sysTime);

Answer (score 4):

This is not how you use PreparedStatements.

First you have to create the statement :

```
preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
```

Then you execute it (after setting the parameters) :

```
preparedStmt.executeUpdate ();
```

For example :

```
String query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO "+ insertAt +"(Name,Location,Time) VALUES(?,?,?)";
preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStmt.setString(1,"xName");
preparedStmt.setString(2,"xLocation");
preparedStmt.setTimeStamp(3,...)
preparedStmt.executeUpdate ();
```

Comment: same exception is coming after that also